# Div resizable two column layout

Tags: html, css, layout

How to create a `div` layout consisting of 2 columns that, taken together, span 100% of the `body` and where the width of the first column can be changed (horizontal). The second column should adapt such that still 100% of the `body` is filled.

I.e. like [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_two_columns) but with the option to resize the columns as described.

Comment: Do you want to change the first column directly in the browser? If yes, you could find a similar solution here: https://codepen.io/barbalex/pen/ogZWNV

Comment: yes, I want to change the column directly in the browser (interactively). Is there a simpler solution (without bootstrap and less code)?

Comment: It jQuery possible?

Comment: Is possible, but only if necessary. I thought it's can be done by some (simple) extensions to the example in the link, but I couldn't arrange the options in the right way yet.

Comment: You could try https://github.com/nathancahill/Split.js, because it has no Deps, otherwise I could also help you to write your own implementation of that..

Comment: I was wondering if extending the code in my first link a bit for the resize option is possible...

Comment: Can be easily done with the Flexbox.